# How to use an ID inside a variable

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been making a user info commmand, and I have just figured out how to get an ID from a mention. This means people can mention others and see their information.

I have placed the ID inside a variable called `userid1`, and swapped `message.author` in favour of `userid1`, it runs numerous errors, and when it does work just displays everything as undefined.

I tried using `parseInt(userid1)` to see if that would change anything but the same issues arose.

My code looks like this:

```
userid1 = message.mentions.users.first().id;
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .addAuthor(userid1.username);
```

I don't know if it's possible to use a variable as a placeholder for that, so if it is something else please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`User.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id) is a string, not the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object itself, so you can't access user properties.
Instead of storing the user id, you could store the user itself: when you need the id you use [`User.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id), but in this way if you need other properties you can access them too.
Also, please note that `RichEmbed.addAuthor()` does not exist, use [`RichEmbed.setAuthor()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setAuthor).

Try this:

```
let target_user = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!target_user) target_user = message.author;
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor(target_user.username, target_user.avatarURL);
```

Comment: What does the `if (!target)_user) target_user = message.author;` mean and do? I also tried this and if I mention someone it does not give their information. I can only use it without mentioning someone and it returns my results.

Comment: That works for me...
That line is meant to avoid sending undefined data, since if there are not mentioned users it won't work. Are you sure that you wrote that right? It's `if (!target_user)` not `(!target)_user)`
If that's not the case and it doesn't work, send me your code via hastebin.com

Comment: That was not the case, I had written the correct way and I am just making typos. https://hastebin.com/guqabadaso.cs

Comment: That's weird, what does it do when you mention someone?

Comment: Oh I figured out the problem: in your `if` check you're checking if the content is "stest3", but when you add an argument that's not the case...
You should use `if (message.content.startsWith("stest3")) {...}`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't realise that. It works now, thanks!